# Best way to change the behavior depending on the environment variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I sometimes face the situation which could be better to handle flow differently depending on the environment. (Ex. disable some features)

For example.
If you are on the *production*, you can send a email if the process is succeeded.
But for *test*, and *development* environment we just simply disable it.

For now, I just put `if-clause`.

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    itemable = create_invoiceitemable(each_line)
    next unless itemable.present?

    create_invoiceitem(invoice, itemable, each_line[:id])
  end
  ReceiptMailer.receipt(invoie[:uuid]).deliver_later if RAILS_ENV[:production]
```

Any ideas for better way to handle this?

Comment: I suggest using the dedicated method for such a check: `if Rails.production?`. You will gain a better maintainability.

Comment: For the email sending I generally use this gem https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener which will open the email right in the browser instead of sending it in development.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to answer an exact question, since it’s heavily opinion-based, but you might find useful stubbing such methods with:

**config/initializers/stubs.rb**

```
ReceiptMailer.prepend(Module.new do
  def receipt(*args)
    Logger.info "ReceiptMailer#receipt called with #{args.inspect}"
    Hashie::Mash.new { deliver_later: nil } # to allow call
  end
end) unless RAILS_ENV[:production]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It would be the answer if `deliver_now`, but for `deliver_later` it enqueued the job to redis.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the name of the environment to check if something should be activated or not ..why not use a environment variable which You can set its value în the environment specific file and check its value instead.

This way if You for example deploy your app on Heroku You can enable or disable this 'feature without touching the code or re-deploy every time since this are all available from the interface or command line.

I personally think this is a good approach. There might be other good approaches also.

You can use different gems like dotenv to accomplish this . There might be other gems out there too.

Hope this will help :)